# Prove that $\frac{x^3}{n} + x = 1$ has only one real root, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm supposed to work with a sequence $a_n$ where the $n$-th term is defined as the only real root of the equation:

$$\frac{x^3}{n} + x = 1$$

Prior to that, I'm supposed to prove that it's existence and uniqueness is guaranteed. Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3+nx-n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now $f^{\prime}(x)=3x^{2}+n\geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. This tells us that the function $f$ is monotonically increasing and by the Intermediate Value Theorem it only has one real root.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters:
$$
\frac{x^3}{n}+x-1\to\infty\text{ as }x\to\infty
$$
and
$$
\frac{x^3}{n}+x-1\to-\infty\text{ as }x\to-\infty.
$$
So, because it is continuous, there must be at least one real root (by the Intermediate Value Theorem).  (You can also appeal to the fact that imaginary roots come in conjugate pairs to get there very directly, of course; but, IVT is nice and accessible.)

Now, there are two options: one real root and two imaginary, or three real roots.  As a hint: what does the Mean Value Theorem tell you must be true if there are multiple real roots?